# Countably infinite partition of $\mathbb{R}$, which each partition has arbitrary length $\epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

For any interval $I = (a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, how can we find disjoint partitions (which maybe countably infinite)?

Specifically, for any $I$, how can we construct

$$
I:= \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}I_i
$$

such that

- $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$,
- $a = \inf\{I_1\}$,
- $b = \sup \left\{ \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}I_i \right\}$
- $| I_i | \leq  \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

My idea for this problem is that for any given $\epsilon>0$ (and $\epsilon \leq b-a$), set $L \triangleq \frac{b-a}{\epsilon}$, and construct $I_i$ as follow:

$$
I_i = 
\begin{cases}
(a + (i-1)\epsilon,  a+i\epsilon ] , \text{ if }  i \leq \lceil L\rceil -1  \\ 
(a + (i-1)\epsilon,  a+L\epsilon ] , \text{ if }  i =\lceil L \rceil. 
\end{cases}
$$

Then this interval can be countably infinite because for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we can always find $L$ such that $L > N$.

Could you please help me elaborating such construction? Also, could this logic be extended to all real-line not just $I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: Impossible.

From the last condition $|I_{i}|\leq\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$
and all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, it implies that $|I_{i}|=0$ for each $i$.

Being a countable union of sets of measure zero, $|I|=0$.

Comment: Beware the order of quantifier. You may need to move "for all $\epsilon>0$ to the beginning and write: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a family $\{I_i\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that ...

Comment: Also, do not use the misleading notation $I_i$. Is $I_i$ an interval or just a measurable set? You need to clarify this explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering whether given nonempty intervals $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (whose measure is nonzero), we can partition $I$ into $I_i$ where each $I_i$ has infinitesimal measure or not. I meant $I_i$ be interval.

Comment: Unless we work with hyper-real numbers (you may consult any textbooks about non-standard analysis), infinitesimal does not exist (Infinitesimal is something that contradicts to the Archimedean Principle: For any $a>0$ and $b>0$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $na>b$. Hence, infinitesimal is now strictly prohibited in standard analysis.) Therefore, if $|I_i|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, $|I_i|$ can only be zero.